# Making almost a circular form / Making almost a circular form

Tags: semantics

I'm trying to describe a character which happens to be a boar. The boar has two pairs of rusts, a lower pair and an upper pair. 
I want to say that his two upper rusts are uncomenly curved backwards...
Should I say: uncommenly curved backwards making almost a cercle.
Or: uncommenly curved backwards making almost a circular shape.

Comment: Do you mean "tusks" rather than "rusts"?

Comment: You also mean *uncommonly* rather than *uncomenly* or *uncommenty* and *circle* rather than *cercle*.

Comment: You're right, sorry I wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to say "uncommonly curved backwards, almost making a circle". This is because your usage of "almost" suggests that the circle isnt perfect, so using both "almost" and "shape" would be a tautology. (using words that mean the same thing twice)